# Adding Roles In Slash Commands (Discord.Py)

Tags: python, windows, discord, discord.py

```
@tree.command(name = 'redeem', description = 'Redeems A Members Key')
async def redeem(interaction: discord.Interaction, key: str, member:discord.Member):
    with open("bkeys.txt") as f:
        if key in f.read():
            em = discord.Embed(color=0xff0000)
            em.add_field(name="Invalid Key", value="Sorry, this key has been blacklisted")
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=em)
            return 0
    with open("keys.txt") as f:
        if key in f.read():
            role = interaction.guild.get_role(1071561081685811210)
            await member.add_roles(member, role)
            em = discord.Embed(color=0x008525)
            em.add_field(name="Key Redeemed", value="Key has now been redeemed")
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=em)
            f = open("ukeys.txt", "w")
            f.write(key)
            f.write('\n')
        else:
            em = discord.Embed(color=0xff0000)
            em.add_field(name="Invalid Key", value="Inputed key has already been used!")
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=em)
```

[Error](https://pastebin.com/3sF32m3z)

**This has been a command I have been trying to work on its just the add roles will not work, btw im new to python so I don't know much sorry, so if anyone could just drop the code please.
**

I tried changing the (1071561081685811210) to my role name ("Buyer") and asking for help but I didn't understand.

Comment: The error says the role your trying to get doesn't exist. Are you sure that your using the correct role id? You can get the role id by mentioning it and adding a \ before the mention \@role or you can get it by simply going to the role settings and copying it

Comment: Alternatively, you can get the role by using the utility function `discord.utils.get(iterable, *conditions)`. Just pass a list of roles in the server and put a role name. For example, `discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name="Buyer")`

You can read more about the libraries utility functions [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#utility-functions)

Comment: I just noticed you passed `member` when your adding the roles, remove `member` and just put `await member.add_roles(role)`

Answer (score 1):

like [bruh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16964696/bruh) has said you should change

```
member.add_roles(member,role)
```

to

```
member.add_roles(role)
```